# Rotation of the sphere in the photo with CSS

Tags: html, css, django, animation, css-animations

I want this hemisphere in the photo related to Wikipedia to rotate inward with only HTML and CSS codes (like the movement of the earth).
The code that I sent below rotates the entire image, and it is also a 360-degree rotation, not an inward rotation.

```
<img src="{% static "wiki.jpg"%}" alt="wiki.jpg">


img{
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-top: 400px;

}
@keyframes img {
   0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
}

img{
    animation: img 20s ease-in-out  infinite;
}
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qujpS.jpg)

If it is not possible to do this with this image, how can I design a similar image?

Comment: Could you explain what an 'inward' rotation would look like? Also, the image you are using has no concept of 3D, could you say where the extra information (ie the rest of the sphere) would come from on a rotation?

Comment: @ A Haworth Hi...Suppose this globe is the Earth in space. I want a movement similar to the movement of the earth around itself for this sphere.
The back hemisphere of this sphere is similar to this hemisphere.

Comment: But the image you give isn’t even a whole hemisphere, let alone a continuous (on a spherical surface) image.

Comment: @AHaworth So how can I have an animation with such conditions???

Comment: You can't have a proper animation given the incomplete image

Comment: @AHaworth I'm sorry. I think I'm not explaining fully. If I want to have such an animation, what features should the image have? What codes are needed?